# When I use zip, how can I display the overall progress without flooding the command line?

Tags: bash, terminal, zip, progress-information

A fixed-length progress bar, a file or byte count, or better yet a timer showing the estimated time remaining would be ideal.

`zip`'s standard behavior seems to be to print a line for every file processed, but I don't want that information overload when I zip thousands of files. I want a guesstimate how long it's going to take.

I tried the `-q` (`--quiet`) option in combination with `-dg` (`--display-globaldots`) but that just floods stdout with multiple lines of dots and gives no useful indication.

I also tried `-qdgds 10m` as mentioned in the man page, but got the same result.

I then tried `-db` (`--display-bytes`) and `-dc` (`--display-counts`) but there doesn't seem to be a global option, so it again prints it for every filename.

Lastly, I tried it together with `-q` like `-qdbdc`, but that just outputs nothing.

Funnily enough, I found a man page on the info-zip site that mentions a `-de` (`--display-est-to-go`) option which should "Display an estimate of the time to finish the archiving operation."

That sounds exactly like what I want, but the problem is that my version of `zip` does not have that feature. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 64bit, bash-4.3.30(1) and zip-3.00. According to Wikipedia, this is zip's latest stable release.

There are unreleased beta versions on the info-zip sourceforge page, but I'd rather not entrust my data to a beta release.

Comment: Log the output to a file and use it to provide high level info with `tee`. Before starting zip, make a total count of the files (with `ls` or `find -type f`) and while it is zipping, read the log file for the number of lines of processed files it already has (with `grep` for the right lines to look at, and `wc -l` for the lines count), so your high level info will show something like "234/76438 files processed";

Comment: you can work the timing by considering the total files size and checking the size of the ones that were already processed; but... even files with the same size take different time to be processed so it will always be a wild guess...

Comment: I don't know if you can use stdin when making ZIP files, but if gzip is okay, you can do something like `pv /path/to/file | gzip > /path/to/file.gz`

Answer (score 30):

If you're ok with using 7z:

```
7z a output.zip folder/
```

This will give you a progress bar like this:

```
Open archive: test.zip
--
Path = test.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 232039663

Scanning the drive:
3 folders, 2401 files, 238122225 bytes (228 MiB)

Updating archive: test.zip

Items to compress: 2404

 16% 279 U folder/file.txt
```

Comment: When I finally made zip's -rqdgds option work, it showed each dot on the next line, which is useless if you need more than a few dozen dots. So 7z was indeed the simplest way to go.

Comment: @Rodrigo sometimes the best answer is to just use a different tool.

Answer (score 25):

`zip` can compress data to standard output. Hence, you can combine it with other tools like `pv`:

```
zip -qr - [folder] | pv -bep -s $(du -bs [folder] | awk '{print $1}') > [file.zip]
```

Remove one of the `-bep` options as your convenience.

Comment: Thanks for this! I do this on my mac (brew install pv, brew install coreutils, and replace du with gdu).

Answer (score 5):

I have successfully used the following:

```
zip -r [target_zip] [folder_to_zip] 2>&1 | 
pv -lep -s $(ls -Rl1 [folder_to_zip] | egrep -c '^[-/]') > /dev/null
```

And this is explained below:

```
zip -r [target_zip] [folder_to_zip] 2>&1 |
```

zip recursively into [target_zip] file the [folder_to_zip] redirecting stderr to stdout. Note that stderr will contain **one line for each file and directory** being processed.

```
pv -lep -s $(ls -Ral1 [folder_to_zip] | egrep -c '^[-/]') > /dev/null
```

pipe into `pv` the lines with the filenames as they are being output from zip. `pv` is operated in line mode (counting progress based on lines and size is also in number of lines to expect – see [PV man page -l option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)).

The total size of lines to expect is gathered by recursively listing (ls) the [folder_to_zip] and counting the lines starting with '-' or 'd', i.e., **all the files and directories (remember directories are listed starting with '/' )**.

The above provides accurate percentage of completion as the 100% is reached when all files and directories have been processed.

The problem with the answer of pedroapero is that progress is calculated on number of bytes processed (compressed) over the total number of bytes to process (uncompressed). As a result the process will complete at around 30% (depending on the compression rate).

Comment: Thanks for your additional reply. That's correct, I guess it all depends of file size distribution, and content entropy.

Comment: Great explanations!

Answer (score 3):

Use (-q)[--quiet] option , like `zip -q ....` see man zip for more https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip

Comment: Does that show the progress?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `-qq` flag to the command. This worked for me.
Example:

```
zip -r -qq out_chairs.zip out_chairs/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would use grep expression

```
egrep -c '^([-d][rwx-]{9})'
```

At least for me on Ubuntu, no directory starts with "/" but rather with "d" (sure you could use [-d] only, but I was not sure about the recursive output of 'ls'.

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 user user 4096 apr 14  2015 gems
```

Also note we are not counting in hidden files here (or better said, the first instance of the command Lefteris wrote). And due to "." and ".." I would say the counts will be off (the more complex the directory tree, the worse estimate for the pv) if we use switch "-a". So that could also be somehow taken care of in the grep or perhaps in ls depending on your system.

Comment: did you answer the wrong question?

Comment: You are probably right. I've reiterated on one of the answers here. So I better find the exact usage of the zip I did and edit my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would better use:

```
cat INPUTFILE.img | pv -bep -s $(du -bs INPUTFILE.img | awk '{print $1}') | zip -q > OUTPUTFILE.zip
```

In that case you see real percentage of data through "PV"
The only trouble now is file name, which can be solved:

```
echo -e "@ -\n@=NEWNAME.img" | zipnote -w OUTPUTFILE.zip
```

Or both commands in one line:

```
cat INPUTFILE.img | pv -bep -s $(du -bs INPUTFILE.img | awk '{print $1}') | zip -q > OUTPUTFILE.zip ; echo -e "@ -\n@=NEWNAME.img" | zipnote -w OUTPUTFILE.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I read up on the zip man page on my MacOS (`man zip`), and read this which worked great for me - quoting from the man page output:

```
-dg
--display-globaldots
    Display progress dots for the archive instead of for each file.  The command

        zip -qdgds 10m

    will turn off most output except dots every 10 MB.
```

For example, this is the command I used to zip up the folders in the working directory:

```
for dir in */ ; do
   echo "Zipping up $dir ..."
   zip -rqdgds 50m ${dir%/}.zip ${dir} -x .git/**\*  -x .zip/**
done
```